# Failed to install BloackHound

Tags: project-reactor

I am just expreminting with BlockHound, trying to run the quick start provided in the documentaion : [BlockHound docs](https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound/blob/master/docs/quick_start.md)

but I get the following exception :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/scheduler/NonBlocking

at reactor.blockhound.integration.ReactorIntegration.lambda$applyTo$0(ReactorIntegration.java:49)
at reactor.blockhound.BlockHound$Builder.nonBlockingThreadPredicate(BlockHound.java:317)
at reactor.blockhound.integration.ReactorIntegration.applyTo(ReactorIntegration.java:49)
at reactor.blockhound.BlockHound$Builder.with(BlockHound.java:353)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reactor.core.scheduler.NonBlocking
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 78 more
```

my pom file dependencies and dependency management :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  <!--  <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>blockhound-junit-platform</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>blockhound</artifactId>
        <!--<version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>-->
        <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-bom</artifactId>
            <version>Bismuth-RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

So what could be wrong regarding this configuration?

Comment: What version of `reactor-core` are you using?

Comment: Bismuth-RELEASE as per the dependency management in the pom file.